# How to run code if yepnope returns true?

Tags: yepnope

I use yepnope.js to load a polyfill (Intl). If window.Intl doesn't exist, it loads my polyfill, and executes some code. However, if windows.Intl does in fact exist, I need to execute another code, and I havn't been able to figure out how.

Here is what I have:

```
yepnope({
  test  : window.Intl,
  nope  : ['lib/Intl.min.js'],
  callback: function(u,r,k){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'sv-SE.json',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        Intl.__addLocaleData(data,"sv-SE");
        self.numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("sv-SE");
      }
    });
  },
  complete: function(){

     /* Do stuff! */
```

The code I need to run if window.Intl already exists is `self.numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("sv-SE");`, but I can't figure out how, as `callback` is only called on false, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't know if there is some kind of nice "yep" callback function inside yepnope. I've solved the very same requirement by moving my "testing if" before the yepnope call into plain JavaScript. You can try to guess by yourself looking here: https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/yepnope.js (start by reading function ```loadFromTestObject```)

Comment: @xmojmr That's what I ended up doing to, but I was hoping for a nicer looking solution. Thanks for the link, anyway!